# Adapt std::pair for STL algorithm lambda

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have STL container with std::pair.
Is there any way to adapt pair's second for STL algorithm lambda using boost?

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, SomeStruct>> vec;
const auto Predicate = [](SomeStruct const& s) { ... };
auto it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), boost-magic(Predicate));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the headers `boost/range/algorithm/find_if.hpp` and `boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp` you could use:

```
auto it = boost::find_if(vec | boost::adaptors::transformed(
  [](std::pair<int, SomeStruct>& p){ return p.second; }),Predicate);
```

I am not aware of something shorter than `[](std::pair<int, MyClass>& p){ return p.second; }`. A raw `std::get<1>` does not work in this context, since it is not a functor. But my c++14-compiler also accepted the expression `[](auto& p){ return std::get<1>(p); }` or `[](auto& p){ return p.second; }`

**Update:** You can use `boost::phoenix::at_c<0>(boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1)` to obtain a function accessing the `first` member of the pair and `boost::lambda::bind(Predicate,boost::lambda::_1)` to make `Predicate` work together with this function and boost::lambda's comma-operator overload to combine both:

```
auto it = boost::find_if(vec, (boost::lambda::bind(Predicate,boost::lambda::_1),boost::phoenix::at_c<0>(boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1)));
```

But I wouldn't call this "boost-magic", it is more like making things unnecessary complex.

Comment: I've seen something similar done with std::vector<int> using boost::arg1. I don't really know how arg1 works but I was wondering if It can be used to adapt std::pair.

Answer (score 6):

No need for boost. You can simply write a lambda, or a named function object:

```
const auto Predicate2 = [&Predicate](std::pair<int, SomeStruct> const& s) {
    return Predicate(s.second);
};
auto it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), Predicate2);
```

Of course, if `Predicate` is only ever used in this one case, then it would make more sense to write it to accept a pair directly.